# Programmatically create blogs with dummy content on a WPMU site

Tags: multisite, testing

I'm trying to set up a WPMU test environment with 5-6K blogs, lots of posts comments, users etc.

Browsing trough the WP's functions, I picked up [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post), [wp_insert_comment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment), [create_empty_blog()](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/create_empty_blog), and [wp_insert_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user).

So basically I would run a big for loop in which I create random blogs, get their ID, switch to each of them and insert posts with [random content](http://www.lorizzle.nl/?feed=1).

Is this really this easy as it looks? :)
Or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Sounds good. I'd also run a performance test when you start it to take the chance to gather some insights.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you take a look at [WP Dummy Content](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dummy-content/).

You can easily extend this plugin or build a script to activate and run it.

As suggested by @kaiser I would really record all the performance data I can to get in insights into this scale of operations.