# Create multiple subdomains for multi-site from a database

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I want to create multiple subdomains for users.
I know how to create multiple subdomains manually using *creating network*.

But, i have so many users, I can't create those subdomains manually one by one.

I have a user list in an Excel file:

```
id || username || password || subdomain

 1 || alex     || ****     || alex.websitewordpress.com

 2 || brad     || ****     || brad.websitewordpress.com

 3 || carol    || ****     || carol.websitewordpress.com

 4 || donald   || ****     || donald .websitewordpress.com
```

How can I create multiple subdomains automatically using the data from my Excel file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *More than an answer, a study on the matter.*

#### The Excel issue

- we need an array, and Excel can provide a CSV
- a couple of solutions: [How to extract data from csv file in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2805427/1287812) <sub>not implemented here</sub>

---

#### Relevant Q&A

What's common to all is: ***no definitive procedure has been recorded in this Stack***.

- [Programmatically create blogs with dummy content on a WPMU site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/14310/12615) <sup>(One Trick Pony's question)</sup>
- [Creating multiple blogs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/28244/12615) <sup>(One Trick Pony's question)</sup>
- [WordPress network: set themes and plugins for new blog](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52127/12615) <sup>(mrwweb's answer)</sup>

---

#### Testing code

- Based on OneTrickPony first Question.
- Must run only ***once***. I don't know of a better method.
- I'm ***not sure*** if `admin_init` is the best place to run this.
- Haven't measured, but this code **does not runs fast** (3 sites in this sample).
- There's an **awful CSS bug** in the admin after running the code. After disabling the hook and reloading the page everything is ok and all sites had been created.

. (!?) [image]

```
/* Enable the hook, refresh the dashboard, <WAIT>, disable again */
// add_action('admin_init','wpse_54647_testing_code');

function wpse_54647_testing_code()
{
    $site = get_current_site();
    
    $meta = array( 
            'blogdescription'       => 'blog description'
        ,   'users_can_register'    => 1 
    );
    
    $sites_array = array(
        
            array(
                    'title'   => 'site 1'
                ,   'domain'  => 'site1'
                ,   'user'    => 'site1'
                ,   'pass'    => 'pass1'
                ,   'email'   => 'user1@email.com'
            )
            
        ,   array(
                    'title'   => 'site 2'
                ,   'domain'  => 'site2'
                ,   'user'    => 'site2'
                ,   'pass'    => 'pass2'
                ,   'email'   => 'user2@email.com'
            )
            
        ,   array(
                    'title'   => 'site 3'
                ,   'domain'  => 'site3'
                ,   'user'    => 'site3'
                ,   'pass'    => 'pass3'
                ,   'email'   => 'user3@email.com'
            )
    );
    
    for( $i = 0; $i < count($sites_array); $i++ )
    {
        $user = wp_insert_user( array (
                                    'user_login' => $sites_array[$i]['user']
                                ,   'user_pass' => $sites_array[$i]['pass'] 
                                ,   'user_email' => $sites_array[$i]['email'] 
                                ) );
        
        $blog_id = wpmu_create_blog(
                $sites_array[$i]['domain'] . '.' . $site->domain
            ,   '/'
            ,   $site_titles[$i]['title']
            ,   $user
            ,   $meta
            ,   $site->id
        );
    }

}
```